# mlr: creating plotBMRBoxplots for only one of the learner

Tags: r, ggplot2, mlr

does anyone know whether it is possible to create the plots integrated in the `mlr` package for only one of the learners?

For example:

```
BMR_Boxplot <- plotBMRBoxplots(bmr, measure = mse) 
BMR_Boxplot
```

Looking at the arguments, I don't see the possibility to choose one specific learner - is there any known workaround?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you subset your bmr object to the results of only one learner, it is easily possible.

Maybe would be nice to have this as feature. 
Example code for subsetting to the first learner:

```
lrns = list(makeLearner("classif.lda"), makeLearner("classif.rpart"))
tasks = list(iris.task, sonar.task)
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 5L)
meas = list(acc, ber)
bmr = benchmark(lrns, tasks, rdesc, measures = meas)
bmr$results[[2]] = NULL
bmr$learners[[2]] = NULL
plotBMRBoxplots(bmr, ber, style = "violin")
```